# 404 error when trying and unable access the sub urls but the server name is running

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf, flask-restful

I am deploying Flask app with httpd 2.4 by using mod_wsgi 4.5 version.

My servername sample.server.com is running fine but when i try with sub url like sample.server.com/app1, am encountering 404 error.

I also tried with localshost/app1 its is working, that means my flask app is tottaly fine but there is some configuration issue which i couldnt figure out.

I am providing with wsgi file and virtualhost config, i tried reading many articles and blogs but i couldnt find the solution.I would appreciate any help, Thanks

app.wsgi-->

```
activate_this = '/home/nmapi/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
import sys
import logging
print(sys.path)
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"home/nmapi/project/dir")

from run import *
```

my vurtual host config is

```
        #ServerName sample.server.com 
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

        WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi 
        /home/nmapi/project/dir/datascience.wsgi
        <Directory /home/nmapi/project/dir/>
                #WSGIProcessGroup score
                #AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                #Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /home/nmapi/project/dir/static
        <Directory /home/nmapi/project/dir/static/>
                WSGIProcessGroup score
                #WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                #AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                #Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog logs/error.log
        #ErrorLog /tmp/error.log
        LogLevel debug
        #CustomLog /tmp/access.log combined
        CustomLog logs/access.log combined
```

Comment: Show how you are setting up your routes. You should not include the mount point for the web application in your routes. So if you are including ``/app1`` in the routes, remove it. BTW, your ``WSGIScriptAlias`` doesn't say ``/app1`` but I will assume you are changing it from what you are using and weren't consistent about it.

Comment: You're right, the mount point is app1. 
However, the issue seems to persist even if I remove the mountpoint in the conf like so: 
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nmapi/project/dir/datascience.wsgi 

When I run the app using simple python, it works well and I am able to access sub-urls. 
For the routes I am using DispatcherMiddleware and I am reading folders and generating urls based on the available apps.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting removing it from ``WSGIScriptAlias``, but from your routes in your code if you had used it there. Have you even tried a WSGI hello world to see if that configuration in Apache is even being matched at all. It sounds a bit like it is matching some other ``VirtualHost`` in the Apache configuration instead, especially if the 404 is coming from Apache.